# Strange step in Noether's Theorem's proof

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

I have an uncertainty about the proof of Noether's Theorem. Many books/notes that I have consulted and also my professor used the following proof:

Let's consider a transformations such as

$$Q_h=q_h+s$$

where $q$ is one of our lagrangian coordinates. We want to demonstrate that:
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial s}=0$$
where $\mathcal{L}(Q,\dot{Q},t)$ is our lagrangian. We procede taking the derivative:

$$\sum_{h}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial Q_h}\frac{\partial Q_h}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{Q}_h}\frac{\partial\dot{Q}_h}{\partial s}$$

we can apply Euler-Lagrange equation and obtain:

$$\sum_{h}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{Q}_h}\frac{\partial Q_h}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{Q}_h}\frac{\partial\dot{Q}_h}{\partial s}$$

because for said equation $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{Q}_h}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial Q_h}$ but also $\frac{\partial\dot{Q}_h}{\partial s}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial Q_h}{\partial s}$ so if we substitute the sum becomes equal to:

$$\sum_h\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{Q}_h}\frac{\partial Q_h}{\partial s}\bigg]$$

which evaluated for $s=0$ is $0$ confirming our thesis.

I can't get why the proof ends like this. It feels like we are talking about a particular case because we nullify our initial transformation. How is this supposed to show the validity of Noether's theorem?

Also I don't understand why imposing $s=0$ should make everything $0$ because in theory $\frac{\partial Q_h}{\partial s}=1$ no matter which value we give to $s$

I leave a screenshot of some notes made by professor David Tong which does the same steps, but it may be helpful if my explanation wasn't clear enough.[image]

Comment: there are about 12 lines in Tong’s notes. Which line are you not convinced by? Next, in your post, you mention *“we want to demonstrate that: $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial s}=0$”*. That is not true. It is our **assumption** that this $s$-partial derivative vanishes. We have to prove **there exists** a quantity $J$ such that $\frac{dJ}{dt}=0$ (the conserved quantity/current).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I was unsure about why we were considering s=0 in our assumption

Comment: Recall that $q(t)$ solves the Euler-Lagrange equations. We now wish to consider a family of curves around it (a one-parameter family/variation) giving a smooth symmetry. So we consider $Q(s,t)$ such that $Q(0,t)=q(t)$. If you’re asking whether $s=0$ is special, then no, we could have relabeled things so that $s=2024$ is the parameter value which coincides with $q(t)$. If your question is whether it really is important that for **some** value $s_0$, we have $Q(s_0,t)=q(t)$, then the answer is yes, because we are using the Euler-Lagrange equations so we need a solution of it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo but if I want to show that no matter how I transform the system using my one parameter variation the lagrangian doesn't depend on s, wouldn't be more natural to show that it is so for every possible s?

Comment: Look at definition (2.52). That is for all $s$. It says the Lagrangian doesn’t depend on $s$ (hence why it makes sense to call it a symmetry). The only place $s=0$ is used us when he says (By Lagrange), and the final rqual sign, i.e $s=0$ is used to define the corresponding conserved quantity (and show that it actually is conserved by invoking Euler-Lagrange).

Comment: But really though, the proof shows that it suffices for the derivative in (2.52) to vanish at $s=0$, so we get something more general… Notice that a derivative being zero means we’re at a critical point (or in sloppy language, infinitesimally constant), hence why this is actually all we need to prove the theorem.